# Laravel - not connection to DB on docker

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, postgis

I'm trying to run Laravel with postgres db. Docker build works fine I have access to app thru url and can connect to db. But laravel cant establish connection to db.

My connection to db using phpstorm client works:
[image]

But when I use the same credentials in env file:

[image]

then I have following error.

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException  : SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not
> connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> at
> /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31
> 27|             parent::__construct($dsn, (string) $user, (string) $password, (array) $options);
> 28|             $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, [PDOStatement::class, []]);
> 29|             $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
> 30|         } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
>
> > 31|             throw new PDOException($exception);
> > 32|         }
> > 33|     }
> > 34|
> > 35|     /**

Docker config:
**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgis:
    image: postgis/postgis
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test123
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  php-hap:
    build: php-fpm-hap
    container_name: php-hap
    ports:
      - '9002:9002'
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/html
      - ./logs/happy_hours:/var/www/html/var/logs
    links:
      - postgis
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    links:
      - php-hap
    volumes_from:
      - php-hap
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
```

init.sql

```
 CREATE USER happy_user WITH PASSWORD 'test';
    CREATE DATABASE happy_user_db;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE happy_user_db TO happy_user;
```

php-fpm dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        nano \
        libxslt1.1 \
        libxslt1-dev \
        unzip \
        git \
        gnupg \
        libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql --with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd xsl pdo pdo_pgsql

# Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "error_reporting = E_ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "display_startup_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "display_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.profiler_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp/snapshots" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.max_nesting_level=9999" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs

RUN set -xe; \
    curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -; \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list; \
    apt-get update >/dev/null; \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install >/dev/null \
        nodejs \
        yarn \
    ;\
    apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;

ENV PHP_IDE_CONFIG "serverName=happy_hours_app"

RUN curl --insecure https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.19/composer.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

# Set timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime
RUN "date"

RUN printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "Europe/Warsaw"\n' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

ngnx config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-hap:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: can you try using the container name instead of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"? Also try to set the DB_HOST via the environment tag directly in the compose file, instead of using a dedicated env file.
Like this:
`environment:
    DB_HOST: postgis
`
Don't forget to remove the definition from the env file!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to change DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to postgis in env file , it work form me .
like this :-
DB_HOST=postgis

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It worked by changing the DB_HOST to the same name as the database service in the docker-compose file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35662013)